# Call function when "on scroll" event is triggered

Tags: jqgrid

I have a grid that is locally initialized from an array data. after adding the rows to it I want to be able to get the event of the scrollbar when it reaches to the end and load more rows locally.
(the grid has certain height and `'overflow-y' : scroll`)

How can this be done?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the code for loading more data at line 1831 of [grid.base.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js):

```
            case "local":
            case "clientside":
                beginReq();
                ts.p.datatype = "local";
                var req = addLocalData();
                addJSONData(req,ts.grid.bDiv,rcnt,npage>1,adjust);
                $(ts).triggerHandler("jqGridLoadComplete", [req]);
                if(lc) { lc.call(ts,req); }
                $(ts).triggerHandler("jqGridAfterLoadComplete", [req]);
                if (pvis) { ts.grid.populateVisible(); }
                endReq();
```

The good news is that the [`loadComplete`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) event is called, so you can put your code there. The only complication is that `loadComplete` may also be called when the grid is initially constructed, so you have to take that into account as well.

Comment: I used `$(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scroll(function(e){});` to catch the onscroll event, and then calculated the bottom. but thank's for the answer anyway.